# drush only runs with sudo

Tags: drush

When I run `drush` without `sudo` I get the header plus: `drush` is designed to run via the command line. Drush with `sudo` works as intended.

I have read that: You do not need root-level permissions to use Drush: it'll work as long as the user invoking it has direct access to the Drupal installation directory.

This does not seem to be true in this case. Even when I `su` to the exact user that owns the Drupal installation, I still cannot run Drush without the error message.

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 ouruser www-data     4096 May 18  2012 html
```

Is there something incorrect about permissions or is there another problem going on?

Comment: Depends.  What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Error message is: drush is designed to run via the command line. Also I get a header, html/text.

Comment: Sounds like are using a different php with sudo than without.  Check $PATH in both environments. You should be using php-cli with Drush; looks like you are using php-cgi without sudo.  Fix your $PATH in the non-sudo environment so that the same php executable is selected as is in the sudo case.

Comment: Yes, I found a symbolic link to php-cgi in usr/local/bin, the directory with the sym link to drush. Haven't had the time to correct yet, but this seems to be the culprit. Thanks very much, @greg_1_anderson

Answer (score 1):

Greggles comment is most likely correct. Check your php path my going to the phpinfo path in the reports section. The URL is `admin/reports/status/php`.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Greg](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60493/drush-only-runs-with-sudo#comment66552_60493) comment:

> Sounds like are using a different PHP with `sudo` than without. Check `$PATH` in both environments. You should be using php-cli with Drush; looks like you are using php-cgi without `sudo`. Fix your `$PATH` in the non-sudo environment so that the same php executable is selected as is in the `sudo` case.